# How to use Date_sub() function in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

How can I use date_sub() function in hql.
For Example following in sql query:
 select * FROM performance  where performance_id= 8955 and daterangefrom >= (date_sub('2008-12-01 00:00:00',interval 8 hour));

I have to write this in @NamedQuery, so I tried this but not working:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "performance.performanceBySourceId", query = "select p from Performance p where p.source.id = :sourceID and p.dateRangeFrom >= (registerFunction('performance.queryString', new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.STRING, 'date_add('2008-12-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 2 hour))) order by p.dateRangeFrom desc' ")
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem with you, It seems that hibernate dosn't support mysql function of DATE_SUB,  so we have to use the native sql query